# Dynamic LINQ query string for indexing into IEnumerableObjects for efficient Multidimensional Array sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to figure out the most efficient and flexible way to sort a multidimensional array by multiple columns, where the sorting conditions are not known until runtime.

At first I messed around with DataTables and sorting using three different methods: DataTable.Select, DataView.Sort, and using LINQ on the DataTable. The first two methods which allowed you to specify the sort conditions dynamically at runtime by building a sorting string.

After a bit of research I found out about Dynamic LINQ which allows you to do OrderBy, ThenBy etc via a string similar to those passed to DataTable.Select or DataView.Sort: http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

Also about Parallel LINQ so that you can use multiple cores in your sort (not compatible with DataTables since they aren't thread safe): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx

As such I thought that I could perform a multidimensional array sort based on multiple sort conditions supplied at runtime in a more efficiently method than by using a DataTable.

I came up with the code below. However I can only get Dynamic LINQ and Parallel LINQ working if I wrap my data in a custom object since I can't figure out how to build the Dynamic LINQ query string for a List or Jagged Array.

Does anyone know what changes I need to do to my query string for Dynamic LINQ to get my sort working? The string that I am trying to correct in the code below is "0 ASC, 2 DESC, 1 ASC".

Note that when I wrap my data in a custom object called Row, I can build the DLINQ string fine and have it sort properly. But it would be nice to get rid of the extra overhead that this will produce.

My code below sorts a test array by 3 columns. I use a mixture of test cases for various methods of doing it using LINQ and Dynamic LINQ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace MultiDimensionalArraySorting
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var testArray = new IComparable[,]{
            {1, "a", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)},
            {2, "a", new DateTime(2000, 1, 2)},
            {1, "c", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)},
            {5, "a", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)},
            {2, "a", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)},
        };
        int numRows = testArray.GetLength(0);
        int numCols = testArray.GetLength(1);

        var listOfRows = TwoDimensionalArrayToListOfRows(testArray);

        var aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfRows = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedByLinqOnListOfRows = listOfRows.AsParallel().OrderBy(r => r.Values[0]).ThenByDescending(r => r.Values[2]).ThenBy(r => r.Values[1]);
        ListOfRowsToTwoDimensionalArray(sortedByLinqOnListOfRows, ref aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfRows);
        Console.WriteLine("\nLinq on list of custom type:");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfRows);

        var aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfRows = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedByDLinqOnListOfRows = listOfRows.AsParallel().OrderBy("Values[0] ASC, Values[2] DESC, Values[1] ASC");
        ListOfRowsToTwoDimensionalArray(sortedByDLinqOnListOfRows, ref aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfRows);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDLinq on list of custom type:");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfRows);

        var listOfList = TwoDimensionalArrayToListOfList(testArray);

        var aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfList = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedByLinqOnListOfList = listOfList.AsParallel().OrderBy(r => r[0]).ThenByDescending(r => r[2]).ThenBy(r => r[1]);
        ListOfListToTwoDimensionalArray(sortedByLinqOnListOfList, ref aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfList);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nLinq on list of list:");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingLinqOnListOfList);

        var aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfList = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedByDLinqOnListOfList = listOfList.AsParallel().OrderBy("0 ASC, 2 DESC, 1 ASC"); //The string provided is incorrect here
        ListOfListToTwoDimensionalArray(sortedByDLinqOnListOfList, ref aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfList);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDLinq on list of list (incorrect):");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingDLinqOnListOfList);

        var jaggedArray = TwoDimensionalArrayToJagged(testArray);

        var aSortedUsingLinqOnJagged = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedJaggedLinq = jaggedArray.AsParallel().OrderBy(r => r[0]).ThenByDescending(r => r[2]).ThenBy(r => r[1]);
        JaggedArrayToTwoDimensional(sortedJaggedLinq, ref aSortedUsingLinqOnJagged);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nLinq on jagged array:");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingLinqOnJagged);

        var aSortedUsingDLinqOnJagged = new IComparable[numRows, numCols];
        var sortedUsingDLinqOnJagged = jaggedArray.AsParallel().OrderBy("0 ASC, 2 DESC, 1 ASC"); //The string provided is incorrect here
        JaggedArrayToTwoDimensional(sortedUsingDLinqOnJagged, ref aSortedUsingDLinqOnJagged);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDLinq on jagged array(incorrect):");
        PrintMultiDimensionalArray(aSortedUsingDLinqOnJagged);

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void PrintMultiDimensionalArray(IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int rowStart = a.GetLowerBound(0);
        int rowEnd = a.GetUpperBound(0);
        int colStart = a.GetLowerBound(1);
        int colEnd = a.GetUpperBound(1);
        for (int r = rowStart; r <= rowEnd; r++)
        {
            if (colStart != colEnd)
            {
                for (int c = colStart; c < colEnd; c++)
                    Console.Write("{0}, ", a[r, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(a[r, colEnd]);
        }
    }

    static void JaggedArrayToTwoDimensional(IEnumerable<IComparable[]> jagged, ref IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int rowStart = a.GetLowerBound(0);
        int colStart = a.GetLowerBound(1);
        int rowIndex = rowStart;
        foreach (var row in jagged)
        {
            int colIndex = colStart;
            foreach (var val in row)
            {
                a[rowIndex, colIndex++] = val;
            }
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }

    static void ListOfListToTwoDimensionalArray(IEnumerable<List<IComparable>> rows, ref IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int r = 0;
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            int c = 0;
            foreach (var val in row)
                a[r, c++] = val;
            r++;
        }
    }

    static void ListOfRowsToTwoDimensionalArray(IEnumerable<Row> rows, ref IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int r = 0;
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            int c = 0;
            foreach (var val in row.Values)
                a[r, c++] = val;
            r++;
        }
    }

    static List<Row> TwoDimensionalArrayToListOfRows(IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int rowStart = a.GetLowerBound(0);
        int rowEnd = a.GetUpperBound(0);
        var l = new List<Row>(rowEnd - rowStart + 1);
        for (int r = rowStart; r <= rowEnd; r++)
            l.Add(new Row(a, r));
        return l;
    }

    static List<List<IComparable>> TwoDimensionalArrayToListOfList(IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int rowStart = a.GetLowerBound(0);
        int rowEnd = a.GetUpperBound(0);
        int numRows = rowEnd - rowStart + 1;
        int colStart = a.GetLowerBound(1);
        int colEnd = a.GetUpperBound(1);
        int numCols = colEnd - colStart + 1;
        var l = new List<List<IComparable>>(numRows);
        for (int r = rowStart; r <= rowEnd; r++)
        {
            var row = new List<IComparable>(numCols);
            for (int c = colStart; c <= colEnd; c++)
                row.Add(a[r, c]);
            l.Add(row);
        }
        return l;
    }

    static IComparable[][] TwoDimensionalArrayToJagged(IComparable[,] a)
    {
        int rowStart = a.GetLowerBound(0);
        int rowEnd = a.GetUpperBound(0);
        int numRows = rowEnd - rowStart + 1;
        int colStart = a.GetLowerBound(1);
        int colEnd = a.GetUpperBound(1);
        int numCols = colEnd - colStart + 1;

        var jagged = new IComparable[numRows][];
        for (int r = rowStart; r <= rowEnd; r++)
        {
            int rowIndex = r - rowStart;
            jagged[rowIndex] = new IComparable[numCols];
            for (int c = colStart; c <= colEnd; c++)
                jagged[rowIndex][c - colStart] = a[r, c];
        }

        return jagged;
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public Row(IComparable[,] a, int rowIndex)
        {
            int colStart = a.GetLowerBound(1);
            int colEnd = a.GetUpperBound(1);
            Values = new IComparable[colEnd - colStart + 1];

            for (int c = colStart; c <= colEnd; c++)
                Values[c - colStart] = a[rowIndex, c];
        }
        public IComparable[] Values { get; private set; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you are supposed to use the keyword 'it' as defined here: 
http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/Expressions

so the sort string in this case would be: "it[0] ASC, it[2] DESC, it[1] ASC"

Will be interesting to see how fast the jagged array approach is on a large dataset. I suspect that it will be significantly faster than using a DataTable